# Active user does not show in real time chat app

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am following up this guide https://www.codechief.org/article/real-time-chat-app-with-laravel-6-vue-js-and-pusher#gsc.tab=0 to create real-time chat app in Laravel and Vue.
But it does not show list of active user.

Also this span never shows

```
<span class="text-muted" v-if="activeUser" >{{ activeUser.first_name }}` is typing...</span>
```

Also, this method does not work properly because in console log it shows undefined is typing...

```
    sendTypingEvent() {
                    Echo.join('chat')
                        .whisper('typing', this.user);
                    console.log(this.user.fist_name + ' is typing now')
}
```

And it is not actually real time, because I see new messages only if I reload page.

This is Vue component

```
   <template>
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-8">
            <div class="card card-default">
                <div class="card-header">Messages</div>
                <div class="card-body p-0">
                    <ul class="list-unstyled" style="height:300px; overflow-y:scroll" v-chat-scroll>
                        <li class="p-2" v-for="(message, index) in messages" :key="index" >
                            <strong>{{ message.user.first_name }}</strong>
                            {{ message.message }}
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <input
                    @keydown="sendTypingEvent"
                    @keyup.enter="sendMessage"
                    v-model="newMessage"
                    type="text"
                    name="message"
                    placeholder="Enter your message..."
                    class="form-control">
            </div>
            <span class="text-muted" v-if="activeUser" >{{ activeUser.first_name }} is typing...</span>
        </div>

        <div class="col-4">
            <div class="card card-default">
                <div class="card-header">Active Users</div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="py-2" v-for="(user, index) in users" :key="index">
                            {{ user.first_name }}
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props:['user'],
        data() {
            return {
                messages: [],
                newMessage: '',
                users:[],
                activeUser: false,
                typingTimer: false,
            }
        },
        created() {
            this.fetchMessages();
            Echo.join('chat')
                .here(user => {
                    this.users = user;
                })
                .joining(user => {
                    this.users.push(user);
                })
                .leaving(user => {
                    this.users = this.users.filter(u => u.id != user.id);
                })
                .listen('ChatEvent',(event) => {
                    this.messages.push(event.chat);
                })
                .listenForWhisper('typing', user => {
                    this.activeUser = user;
                    if(this.typingTimer) {
                        clearTimeout(this.typingTimer);
                    }
                    this.typingTimer = setTimeout(() => {
                        this.activeUser = false;
                    }, 1000);
                })
        },
        methods: {
            fetchMessages() {
                axios.get('messages').then(response => {
                    this.messages = response.data;
                })
            },
            sendMessage() {
                this.messages.push({
                    user: this.user,
                    message: this.newMessage
                });
                axios.post('messages', {message: this.newMessage});
                this.newMessage = '';
            },
            sendTypingEvent() {
                Echo.join('chat')
                    .whisper('typing', this.user);
                console.log(this.user.fist_name + ' is typing now')
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Also, this method does not work properly because in console log it shows undefined is typing..."

i assume you made a typo in your console.log, you probably meant:

this.user.fi**r**st_name

Concerning your "realtime" problem, i suspect it might be because your broadcasted Event is being queued, so you might want to use the **ShouldBroadcastNow** instead of **ShouldBroadcast**

Comment: Thank you for noticing typo, I change it! But after changing ShouldBroadcast in ShouldBroadcastNow, it still does not reload, and do not  show rigth user message (I login in two different browsers, and all messages is displayed by one of them)

Comment: Check on Pusher logs if the event is being broadcasted correctly